# rm cached files are not deleted from commit

Tags: git

I have already deleted a file from git usin git rm --cached filename because it was a large file. But when I want to push it says that the file still exists.

Can you please help? I do not want to push this large file and use git large files.

I have also deleted the file in my project but when I again tried using git rm --cached it says that the file does not exist but when I commit and want to push, it shows that this large file exists and can not do the push.

Comment: Or maybe it would be sufficient to do `git rebase -i` and `edit` a more recent commit where you added the file.

Comment: The key word here is "history". You can remove the file from _this_ commit but that does not remove it from _past_ commits. That's what Git _is_ — a collection of _past commits_.